# Using QgsSpatialIndex for spatial join

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I've written a bit of code to do a simple spatial join in QGIS 2 and 2.2 (points that lie within a buffer to take attribute of the buffer). However, I'd like to employ a QgsSpatialIndex in order to speed things up a bit. Where can I go from here:

```
pointProvider = self.pointLayer.dataProvider()
rotateProvider = self.rotateBUFF.dataProvider()

all_point = pointProvider.getFeatures()
point_spIndex = QgsSpatialIndex()
for feat in all_point:
    point_spIndex.insertFeature(feat)

all_line = rotateProvider.getFeatures()
line_spIndex = QgsSpatialIndex()
for feat in all_line:
    line_spIndex.insertFeature(feat)

rotate_IDX = self.rotateBUFF.fieldNameIndex('bearing')
point_IDX = self.pointLayer.fieldNameIndex('bearing')

self.pointLayer.startEditing()
for rotatefeat in self.rotateBUFF.getFeatures():
    for pointfeat in self.pointLayer.getFeatures():
        if pointfeat.geometry().intersects(rotatefeat.geometry()) == True:
            pointID = pointfeat.id()
bearing = rotatefeat.attributes()[rotate_IDX]
self.pointLayer.changeAttributeValue(pointID, point_IDX, bearing)
self.pointLayer.commitChanges()
```